# How to use GA SDK in UWP hybrid app?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, uwp, hybrid-mobile-app

I have ported my windows 8 hybrid app to windows 10 UWP app. But there's very few information available on how to use google analytics SDK in HYBRID UWP app. I have tried installing the available danwilson plugin but the window.ga functions do not seem to work. If some information is available kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried installing the available danwilson plugin but the window.ga functions do not seem to work.

This plugin only supports IOS and Android.
If you want to use Google Analytics, you need to install the [Google Analytics SDK 1.3.0](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/616232) to your windows platform project. To do this, follow the steps below:

1. Download the [GoogleAnalyticsSDK.vsix](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1476260) and install it.
2. Open the solution under your project `folder->platforms->windows->CordovaApp.sln`.
3. In CordovaApp.windows10(Universal Windows) project right-click `reference-> add reference->Universal Windows->Extensions->UAP version of Analytics SDK`:
   [image]
4. Change the project architecture to `x86`. `Any Cpu` and `x64` will get you error.
5. And also you might need to add the [analytics.xml](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#deploy/content/uap10.0/analytics.xml) and change it manually in `CordovaApp.Windows10(Universal Windows)` project

Now you can use the API offered by GoogleAnalyticsSDK in your Cordova Project:
[image]

**Notes:** For details of using Google Analytics SDK, please refer to [Getting Start(Javascript Apps)](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20%28JavaScript%20apps%29&referringTitle=Documentation#config). Since the SDK is installed in the generated project, you won't get intellisense support in cordova project. Currently I couldn't find a success way to add the SDK to the cordova project layer.

Comment: I get the error-**Unable to get property 'trackView' of undefined or null reference** Note that I am following the link : https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin. This plugin works for hybrid UWP app?Its specified no-where if it can eb used for hybrid UWP app or not.

Comment: Also I get the warnings when I add SDK following the steps above:Could not resolve this reference.                                                                          **Could not locate the assembly "GoogleAnalytics". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk**.    **Project "CordovaApp.Windows10" depends upon SDK "Google Analytics SDK v1.3" which supports apps targeting "UAP 10.0". To verify whether "Google Analytics SDK v1.3" is compatible with "UAP 10.0.10586.0"**

Comment: Sorry, I got it confusing. This plugin only support IOS and Android. For using Google Analytics in Cordova UWP App, you need to install this Google Analytics SDK in the above way. I know it's not a very good way to add google analytics support for cordova app. but it's a successful way :)

Comment: One more thing to notice: You need to change the project architecture to x86 or x64, `Any CPU` will get you error.

Comment: Which assembly did you add? There are three of them, one for windows 8.1 one for windows 8 and one for UAP. Add the UAP one.

Comment: I have added the same assembly as shown by you in the screenshot.

Comment: Did VS added `Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps` automatically? And is there any error? If there is no error, you can try ignoring the warning.

Comment: Yes, when I changed the build version to UAP 10.0 it automatically adds Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps and shows error.

Comment: Strange, I didn't get this error. Maybe share the demo project through online repository?

Comment: Sorry I just tried to build it with Architecture x64, which also throws me an error like yours. It seems not able to run on architecture x64. Only support x86.

Comment: **Project "CordovaApp.Windows10" depends upon SDK "Google Analytics SDK v1.3" which supports apps targeting "UAP 10.0". To verify whether "Google Analytics SDK v1.3" is compatible with "UAP 10.0.10240.0"** And when I change the build version to 10.0 it throws error irrespective of the architecture. If you want I shall share the demo project.

Comment: Yes, I got this error too, when I use the architecture x64. You need to change it to x86.

Comment: Th error persists even after changing the architecture to x86.

Comment: Maybe share the project. I'll check it.

Comment: yes, it will always shows error as Google analytics SDK support  version uptill UAP 10.0.and my build version is 10.0.10240.0(if I change the version it automatically adds the Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps).I am sorry but I am new and not aware of the online repository.

Comment: You can send it to my E-Mail: xiaxucheng@gmail.com

Comment: I downloaded your project and open the project. After retargeting the project  to 10.0.10240.0. The project builds fine.